# userform loop for hiding and unhiding through multiple sequences

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, combobox, userform

So i have this string of code... It is in a userform and is all vba based (IE not pulling data from a spreadsheet.)

Private Sub CHECK1_Click()

```
If CHECK1.value = False Then
    COMBO1.visible = False
        Else
            COMBO1.visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

It works for perfectly for exactly one checkbox and combobox pair, I need it to work on all 61 on of them, individually... Being new to this I looked at case select possability but it looks like i would have to spell in out.

the userform is called "ORDER1"

All of the check boxes are named "CHECK1" THROUGH "CHECK61"

They all correspond to the combobox' aptly named "COMBO1" THROUGH "COMBO61"

(CHECK1=COMBO1 throguh the entire form.)

How can I make this work without putting 61 'click' events into the code?
oh and I'm on excel 2010

Comment: Similar recent question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390719/need-to-use-the-spinbutton-change-sub-but-i-dont-know-the-number-of-spin-butto/51431879#51431879   "Control array" is the term you want to search for.   BTW it's best to avoid all-caps text here - online it's often taken for SHOUTING.

Comment: I will look into it... And that is just the case that i used in the target names. Not yelling, i do apologize.

Comment: I meant your question title...

Comment: oops... "face palm"

Comment: So it might be a dumb way to do it but i took that string of code and went into a spread sheet and broke is apart where i needed to to combine excel auto counting and the =CONCATENATE function...

Comment: That works too!   BTW your code simplifies to `COMBO1.visible = CHECK1.Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments there's already a "control array" with WithEvents as a possible solution, below I'll show another solution without the WithEvents:

Copy this code to Notepad and save it as CatchEvents.cls

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CatchEvents"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Private Type GUID
      Data1 As Long
      Data2 As Integer
      Data3 As Integer
      Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
      Private Declare PtrSafe Function ConnectToConnectionPoint Lib "shlwapi" Alias "#168" (ByVal punk As stdole.IUnknown, _
              ByRef riidEvent As GUID, ByVal fConnect As Long, ByVal punkTarget As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef pdwCookie As Long, _
              Optional ByVal ppcpOut As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
     Private Declare Function ConnectToConnectionPoint Lib "shlwapi" Alias "#168" (ByVal punk As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef riidEvent As GUID, _
              ByVal fConnect As Long, ByVal punkTarget As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef pdwCookie As Long, Optional ByVal ppcpOut As Long) As Long
#End If

'All Other Control-Events also possible
'No need to use WithEvents
'No need to put every Type of control in seperate collection or array, each event will fire no matter which control,
'so in the eventcode controls can be separated from others
'you can give your controls additional properties
'Arguments as Cancel, KeyCode, KeyAscii , Button , x and Y still can be used

Private EventGuide As GUID
Private Ck As Long
Private ctl As Object
Private CustomProp As String

Public Sub MyListClick()
Attribute MyListClick.VB_UserMemId = -610
If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
ctl.Parent.Controls(Replace(ctl.Name, "CHECK", "COMBO")).Visible = ctl.Value
End If
End Sub

Public Sub ConnectAllEvents(ByVal Connect As Boolean)
      With EventGuide
          .Data1 = &H20400
          .Data4(0) = &HC0
          .Data4(7) = &H46
      End With
      ConnectToConnectionPoint Me, EventGuide, Connect, ctl, Ck, 0&
End Sub

Public Property Let Item(Ctrl As Object)
      Set ctl = Ctrl
      Call ConnectAllEvents(True)
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
      If (Ck <> 0) Then Call ConnectAllEvents(False)
      Set ctl = Nothing
End Sub
```

In the VBA-editor right click somewhere on your Project and choose Import file, a Class named CatchEvents will now be in your Class Modules.

Finally paste code below behind your Userform:

```
Private AllControls() As New CatchEvents    

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim j As Long
ReDim AllControls(Controls.Count - 1)
    For j = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
         AllControls(j).Item = Controls(j)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
Dim j As Long
  For j = LBound(AllControls) To UBound(AllControls)
          AllControls(j).Clear
      Next j
      Erase AllControls
End Sub
```