# VBA Class Module: master control of 25 checkboxes and textboxes for 3 different modules

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA class module help for 3 exact userforms with different userform names. Each comprise of 25 textboxes and checkboxes with common naming system "checkbox_x" and "textbox_x" with x as integer.

Goal: on textbox change, check checkbox next to it. Master class module for all 25 textboxes & checkboxes to not have to repeat 25 change events for all three modules.

[image: userform1]

Comment: So you're saying that whenever the user changes/adds a buyer code that you want it to automatically check the box next to it?

Comment: If so it should be pretty trivial to catch that change with a `Textbox_Change()` event which sets the corresponding checkbox to true. I'd be interested to know, though, if there's some way that it could capture a change in *any* textbox so that you dont have to repeat your code 25 times

Comment: I'm looking for a master class module for all 25 textboxes & checkboxes so i dont have to repeat 25 change events for all three modules

Comment: Two different approaches at the bottom of this page https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/820733-one-code-multiple-userform-control-changes.html

Comment: What should happen when CheckBoxes get clicked? +The Change-Event gets fired everytime when a presses a keyboard-key (so SPACE, BACKSPACE will fire change event twice, gets your CheckBox checked and the TextBox is empty)

Comment: + 3 exact Userforms ==> You could use 3 intances of the same Userform.

Comment: Check the checkbox when entering in the textbox. would it be an afterupdate event for the textbox then? check checkbox after textbox update

Comment: Yes, this one you can't use with WithEvents, but you could catch this Event with the ConnectToConnectionPoint api

Comment: is ConnectToConnectionPoint Api a vba function? could you show me a script example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510312/userform-loop-for-hiding-and-unhiding-through-multiple-sequences

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    CheckBox1.Value = True
End Sub
```

Comment: i want a master class module for all 25 textboxes & checkboxes